# Android Slider or Puzzle CAPTCHA

Tags: android, recaptcha, captcha

I have seen slider CAPTCHA implemented in some android apps. I have no idea how it works and how to implement it. I want to implement it in my android app but i couldn't find much help online. Please give me some suggestions and recommendations. What i want to implement can be seen in picture below[image: Geetest CAPTCHA]

This picture is from GeeTest CAPTCHA but this is paid service and i don't want to pay for it. Is there any free alternative?

Comment: Did you get solution to this?

Answer (score -3):

I know this product. I believe it has a free version for everyone, as long as your daily requests are less than 500. Hope that would help.